# Plot two variables in barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I hope you help me, I have a table that represents the percentage of (Mature and Immature) according to height. I wish to represent this data in the form of a graph in the attached photo. the size in the x axis and the% in y and thank you.

Data

```
Size  %Immatures    %Matures      
  6  100.000000   0.000000 
  7  100.000000   0.000000 
  8  100.000000   0.000000 
  9  100.000000   0.000000 
  10  95.454545   4.545455 
  11  82.608696  17.391304
```

plot that i locking for
[image: plot that i locking for]

Answer (score 0):

Bring into long format and use the new columns for y and fill.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.table(text = "Size  %Immatures    %Matures      
6  100.000000   0.000000 
7  100.000000   0.000000 
8  100.000000   0.000000 
9  100.000000   0.000000 
10  95.454545   4.545455 
11  82.608696  17.391304", header = T)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("matures"), 
               names_to = "status", values_to = "values") %>%
ggplot(aes(Size, values, fill = status)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: @kamal please kindly consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers